# SQL Server login -> user mapping not working

Tags: sql, database-administration

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

I restored a database onto a new server and had the change the "database owner" for some unrelated reason.

I create a new login `mylogin` and check off to map to my database which creates a new database user and schema.

When I log in and do

```
select current_user
```

The result is `guest` instead of `mylogin`.  I tried fiddling with granting permissions but then the result is `dbo`.

Even when I do

```
execute as user='mylogin'
select current_user
```

I get `dbo`.

I'm lost.  How do I get `select current_user` to return `mylogin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  The login was added to the `sysadmin` role which forces dbo.